# Running PHP on localhost

Tags: php, html, ajax

On my Mac, I created a simple index.html file that does an ajax call to a local php file. I get this error:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8020/TestApana/command.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I can access the php file directly in my browser (Chrome) by doing:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8020/TestApana/command.php
```

I tested this setup on a separate web browser and it works.
Is there something I need to configure to get the browser to detect/execute the PHP file?

Comment: PHP must be installed.

Comment: Are you running a web server on you PC or just loading the file directly?

Comment: @kkhugs: he said it works when he enters the full path into his browser.

Comment: Is there anything in the web server logs corresponding to the 500 error?

Comment: @Mark: But is it interpreting the PHP file, or just displaying it?

Comment: What is the *exact*(!) address you type in browser to a) reach the index.html b) reach the php file? Can you edit your question and add the urls?

Comment: @kkhugs: Well...he just said "appears". So I guess we have to wait for him to respond.

Comment: I have PHP installed, I'm not running a webserver. I don't know where web server logs are as I'm running it directly (open the file in Chrome)

Comment: If I open the test.php file in the browser, it shows up but I don't think it is executed.

Comment: @Joe - Install something like Apache. Then your URL would be http://localhost/index.php (for example). The web server will then interpret the PHP file and pass the output to the browser. You need to run a web server for the PHP to work.

Comment: Maybe you have some code in your `command.php` that is wrong. What does it do?

Comment: I installed a webserver and PHP and now the code executes.

Comment: PHP 5.4 also has a built-in web server: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the proxy settings of the web browser you are using

OR

change the name of your php file to something else

OR

It means that php is not working on the apache web server on your mac.

Here is what you can do to enable php on your server.

Open terminal app.

```
sudo -s then your password
cd /etc/apahce2
```

backup your http.conf file by typing
    cp http.conf http.conf.backup

```
then open this file in text editor like vi or nano

vi http.conf
```

then find LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
and remove # infront of this line.

save the file

restart apache server by

```
apachectl graceful
```

this will restart your apache webserver